# String Manipulation with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, string

I will have a different type of string(string will not have fixed format,they will be different every time) from them I want to remove some specific substring.Like the string can be

```
FUTIDX 26FEB2009 NIFTY 0
FUTSTK ONGC 27 Mar 2008
FUTIDX MINIFTY 30 Jul 2009
FUTIDX NIFTY 27 Aug 2009
NIFTY FUT XP: 29/05/2008
```

I want to remove the string which starts with `FUT`.
How can I do that ?

Comment: What are the rules for this transformations? E.g. why is the XP in the last string removed?

Comment: I'd say maybe 2 regexes one that captures the date (possibly also remove it from the string, depending on the next approach) and one that either capture the Underlying Type or one that removes the Instrument Type (whichever has fewer alternatives).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString, @"\bFUT\w*?\b", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,What I do is like there is a string like `FUTIDX 26FEB2009 NIFTY 0` Now I first remove the date from the string then I remove the string which starts from `FUT` with the help of your regex,and now remaining string is `NIFTY 0` But I want only `NIFTY`. It is only example but after removing date and removing string which starts with `FUT` from the remaining string I want only `NIFTY`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388%28VS.80%29.aspx) to 'tokenize' the strings. Then check each substring if it [starts with FUT](http://dotnetperls.com/startswith-string).

```
string s = "FUTIDX 26FEB2009 NIFTY 0"
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (word.StartsWith("FUT"))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```